# Google docs spreadsheet event Timer not firing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried applying a very basic script (actually it's just a msgbox for testing purposes) to the google spreadsheet event timer:

Time-driven ---

Minutes timer ---

Every minute

...but it does not execute.

I've attached the same script to an onOpen and onChange event, and those work fine.

I have used the timer in the past (successfully) so is this another unannounced deprecated feature, or ??????

Comment: Wanna bet that you'll be getting an email around midnight, reporting a bunch of script failures because you can't use `Browser` class without a user's browser? The use of `Logger` suggested by @patt0 will be problematic as well, although without failures. You should look at [`BetterLog`](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/betterlog), which will let you direct your logging to a spreadsheet - very handy for debugging trigger functions!

Comment: Yeah... my catch-all test code is WRONG for that specific application.   My bad. NOT catch-all. But it's not like I burned a couple of hours banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what the heck the problem was. Oh wait.....

Comment: Btw, if those emails occurred at the time of failure (instead of at midnight), problem solved immediately.

Comment: Funny you mention that... it's [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#TriggerFail).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. But I had noticed that if I deleted (or even renamed) the script, I would get an email soon afterward indicating that the script could not be found; didn't have to wait until midnight for that type of error announcement via email. And btw, just to put a bow on this: It turns out that I didn't receive even a single email after all of that. Go figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the script will fire every hour, its the Browser.MessageBox which will not fire.  The script may not have a handle to an open spreadsheet when it executes and even less to a browser.

If you use another test, you should see that your script fires, for instance :

```
function timerResponse(e) {
  Logger.log('Timer Fired');

  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(4, 4);
  cell.setValue(e);
}
```

Comment: Wow... good call on my bain fart. MSGBOX won't fire because it can't be dismissed without user response. Many thanks!